# Can't delete record in formview when a value is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, formview, linqdatasource

I am having problems deleting a record in a FormView that is wired up to a LinqDataSource. The table the LinqDataSource is using allows NULL values for almost all fields. If I create a new record in the FormView and fill in all the values, then try to delete it it works fine. However, if I leave any of the fields blank then save and try to delete, it throws the following exception:

> Failed to set one or more properties on type
>   PRIDE.Info___Employee_Health_History.   is not a valid value for
>   Int16.

The same happens for the `real` columns in the table. If I leave one of them blank, then save and try to delete I get the same exception with a different type.

My biggest question is, why is it trying to set ANY values when deleting?

Here's my table:

[image: Table]

My FormView code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvHealthHistory" runat="server" CssClass="full" 
    AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="ldsHealthHistory" DataKeyNames="ID" 
    oniteminserting="fvHealthHistory_ItemInserting">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <p>No records found.</p>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" Text="New Record" CommandName="New" />
        </p>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <table class="pad5">
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Date:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Date", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' />
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="dd MMM yyyy" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Weight:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtWeight" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Weight") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Height:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtHeight" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Height") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Pulse:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPulse" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Pulse") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Systolic:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSystolic" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Systolic") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Diastolic:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDiastolic" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Diastolic") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
        </p>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <table class="pad5">
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Date:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Date", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' />
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="dd MMM yyyy" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Weight:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtWeight" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Weight") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Height:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtHeight" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Height") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Pulse:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPulse" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Pulse") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Systolic:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSystolic" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Systolic") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Diastolic:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDiastolic" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Diastolic") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
        </p>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="pad5">
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Date:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Date", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Weight:</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtWeight" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Weight") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Height:</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtHeight" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Height") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Pulse:</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtPulse" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Pulse") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Systolic:</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtSystolic" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Systolic") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">Diastolic:</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="txtDiastolic" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Diastolic") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" Text="New" CommandName="New" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
        </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" 
        FirstPageText="&amp;lt;&amp;lt; First" LastPageText="Last &amp;gt;&amp;gt;" 
        NextPageText="Next &amp;gt;" PreviousPageText="&amp;lt; Previous" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
</asp:FormView>
```

The LinqDataSoure's ItemInserting event:

```
protected void fvHealthHistory_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    e.Values["Worker_ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
}
```

And finally my LinqDataSource:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsHealthHistory" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="PRIDE.PRIDEDataContext" EnableDelete="True" 
    EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="Date desc" 
    TableName="Info___Employee_Health_Histories" Where="Worker_ID == @Worker_ID">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="Worker_ID" 
            QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
    </WhereParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Date" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Weight" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Height" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Pulse" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Systolic" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Diastolic" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Date" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Weight" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Height" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Pulse" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Systolic" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Diastolic" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Does anybody know why it would only let me delete a record if ALL the nullable fields are filled in?

Comment: what you're fetching in Request.QueryString["id"] [worker_id] or [id]

Comment: I'm fetching `id` in the query string. The LinqDataSource is filtering properly, using the query string variable, it just doesn't want to delete when there are `NULL` values in the FormView itself.